# Precision and Recall of spelling corrector

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I am working on an automated spelling corrector. Now I have to evaluate it.
Therefore I need Precision and Recall and it is absolutely clear how to calculate these. My problem is that I am not sure what **True Positive**, **False Negative**, etc. is.

I think there are two options e.g. for TP (for the other 3 analogous):

**a)** The number of wrong written words which were recognized as wrong

**b)** The number of wrong written words which were corrected into the intended word

I think a) wouldn't say anything about the quality of the correction, but it fits most my intuation of TP.

Best

C.Klaus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A true positive is a wrong word which is properly recognized as wrong, and a true negative is a correct which is properly recognized as correct (and therefore not corrected by your algorithm). The other two are a bit more confusing, but from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives),

> A false positive error, or in short a false positive, commonly called a "false alarm", is a result that indicates a given condition exists, when it does not. For example, in the case of "The Boy Who Cried Wolf", the condition tested for was "is there a wolf near the herd?"; the shepherd at first wrongly indicated there was one, by calling "Wolf, wolf!"

and

> A false negative error, or in short a false negative, is a test result that indicates that a condition does not hold, while in fact it does. I.e., erroneously no effect has been inferred. An example is a truly guilty prisoner who is acquitted of a crime. The condition "the prisoner is guilty" holds (the prisoner is guilty). But the test (a trial in a court of law) failed to realize this, and wrongly decided the prisoner was not guilty, falsely concluding a negative about the condition.

Thus, for example, FN represents all the wrong words which your spell checker missed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So my concern was correct that a TP/FN model says nothing about the correction quality?

Comment: Well, yeah. This model is basically useful for figuring out how good your algorithm is at finding when to correct, but doesn't say much about whether your correction quality is high or low.